# Android - Selector does not work for text in button

Tags: android, button, textcolor

Using Android Studio.  I'm trying to use a selector to make the text in a button turn from white to dark gray.  Only the text, not the background of the button.

Here is my Selector xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
</selector>
```

And here is my Button xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="Maps"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMaps"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonEmail"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@drawable/selector"     <------- **SELECTOR NOT WORKING**
    android:background="#7f2f74a0"             <------- **but it does work if I stick it here**
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

In the preview panel, I receive a rendering error message that reads, "Failed to configure parser for /Users...src/main/res/drawable/selector.xml"

I've tried a number of solutions from SO, and nothing has worked, including cleaning and rebuilding the project.  Interestingly, I got curious and applied the selector to the button's background and it works - the button background defaults to white and changes to gray when pressed.

Anyone smarter than I am have a solution to this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the text selector in color folder under resources instead of drawable.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_focused="true"></item>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false"></item>
    <item android:color="@android:color/white" android:state_enabled="false"></item>
</selector>
```

And the use it like,

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:text="Maps"
    android:id="@+id/buttonMaps"
    android:layout_above="@+id/buttonEmail"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="@color/selector"  
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried this and it still does not work.  Just to be clear, though, I created a new folder named "color" within the "res" directory.  I then moved the selector to that newly created "color" folder.  I an receiving the same error response.

Comment: updated the answer and its working now. just copy the selector and replace you's with mine

Comment: It worked!  Thanks so much for your help.  I was stumped for hours on this.